# ios. UILabel resize issue

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, issuu

I have some issue with labels layout using storyboard.

[image: imageOne]

Left view snapped to labels trailing constraint, and centered according to text, and nothing more. So problem appears when I try to set different text to label, (when text contains number of characters greater then in text on story board). After text has been setting label does't resize it's frame.

Here, how it looks in runtime:

[image: imageTwo]

I have the same issue with other all labels in project, they are don't resize in runtime, but They should. Here is how it should looks like :

[image: imageThree]

I'v already tried to add `layoutIfNeeded()` and `sizeToFit()` to those labels, but it has no effect. I made another project, with pretty same label and constraints, and there it works fine, as should. But not in this project.

What problem could be in?

Comment: Set the `UILabel` to `0` lines, which means that the text all stays on one line.

Comment: The number of lines already been set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It could also depend on when you're setting the text of the label.

If you're setting the text in viewDidLoad try doing it in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Yes , I am trying to move update label code to viewWillAppear but it also has no effect.

Comment: try to put it in viewDidAppear

Comment: Labels places on table view cell, and updates when come response from server. So I am not sure that loading data in view did appear will be a good place to do that.

Comment: Maybe there some property in project settings that cad be set to fix it.?

Comment: As I told before, this issue i have in whole project, with every label.